# How to use google reader feeds in an android application?

Tags: android, rss-reader

I am developing one application where I have to use google reader RSS feeds in my application. Do anybody know how I can receive the google reader headlines which the user has subscribed and then show it in a fragment?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Google feed API](https://developers.google.com/feed/v1/). Also, [JSON format](https://developers.google.com/feed/v1/jsondevguide) is easier to work with.